# changing image s for 1 second in android imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to change image after 1 second for image view.but its doesn't show any image on screen. following is code.please help.thank you.

code-

```
public class Shapes extends Activity {

     Timer timer = new Timer();
     int flag;
     String images[]={};
     ImageView iv;
     static int v[]={R.drawable.round,R.drawable.rectangle};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shapes);
         iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

             public void run() {
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                     public void run() {

                        if (flag > 1) {
                             timer.cancel();
                             timer = null;
                         } else
                             iv.setImageResource(v[flag++]);

                     }
                 });

             }
         }, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000);

    }
}
```

how can i check resource image and change it

Comment: You never initialized the variable `flag`.

Comment: int flag; is the same as int flag = 0; when declaring instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Handler instead of Timer

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable changeImage = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(flag>1)
           handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
        else{
           iv.setImageResource(v[flag++]);
           handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 1000);
        }
    }

};
```

start the first time from oncreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){

    handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

     public void run() {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                 public void run() {
                     flag++;
                      if (flag > 1) {
                          timer.cancel();
                          timer = null;
                      } 
                      else
                          iv.setImageResource(v[flag]);
                     }
                 });

             }
         }, 1000, 1000); // wait 1 second before start.. then repeat every second..
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put System.currentTimeMillis() as delay.
Try replacing that with 0, because the time should start after 0 ms.

Comment: This is wrong, if he would do scheduleAtFixedRate, you would be right!

Comment: All schedule methods of the Timer class have either a Date as the time when the timer should start, or a long as delay.
And currentTimeMillis() returs a long

Comment: @user1669172 its working now..but after that its giving  exception arrayindexoutofboundexception